# onsubmit instead of keyup function

Tags: jquery, forms, youtube

Please check out this url: [Youtube Instant Search](http://demos.9lessons.info/youtube_six_search.html)

As you can see there is a submit on keyup. I want to submit on enter(the normal way)
I tried replacing function keyup with submit but that did not work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the `keyup`, check whether `e.keyCode === 13`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[A working answer](http://jsfiddle.net/FloydPink/sB8HX/embedded/result)

Answer (score 6):

```
$("input").keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        // Do what you want here   
    }    
});
```

`e` is a parameter passed to the function when keyup triggers. It's an object containing:

> originalEvent,type,isDefaultPrevented,timeStamp,jQuery,which,wheelDelta,view,toElement,target,srcElement,shiftKey,screenY,screenX,relatedTarget,relatedNode,prevValue,pageY,pageX,offsetY,offsetX,newValue,metaKey,layerY,layerX,keyCode,handler,fromElement,eventPhase,detail,data,currentTarget,ctrlKey,clientY,clientX,charCode,cancelable,button,bubbles,attrName,attrChange,altKey,namespace,handleObj

We used the `keyCode` object so we can determine which key is pressed. Enter === 13

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$(".search_input").bind("keydown", function(event) {
    if (event.which === 13) {
      // your code
    }
});
```

Or even better, add a button (input type button or submit according to your needs).

Comment: I would indeed go along with `event.which`, as this is recommended (http://api.jquery.com/event.which/).

Comment: "charCode is never set in the keydown and keyup events. In these cases, keyCode is set instead." (`which` is for use when you expect either `keyCode` or `charCode`)

Comment: @Shaz: Thanks for your explanation. However, it might just be a good idea to always use `which` for consistency.

Comment: I wan't to thank everyone for the time and effort. I'm going to use the answer provided by Floyd Pink.

Answer (score 1):

Inputs do not have `onSubmit`, but forms do.  You could wrap that input in a form and add a submit listener to the form.

Comment: Hi, I tried this before and it did not work. Maybe the way I set it up was wrong..Anyway I'm going to use the answer provided by Floyd Pink. Thank's for your effort.